# How is my square wave circuit able to turn itself on?

Tags: bjt, ringing

I built a small 1-to-1 transformer from a ferrite core, to investigate if it could be used as a MOSFET gate drive transformer. I use speaker wire, it has two insulated conductors. I am driving the transformer from a 12 volt DC power supply. The transformer is switched on/off with a 2N5551. The drive signal is generated using a 555 and an additional 2N5551 so that I can have less than a 50% duty cycle. The actual scope trace shows the drive signal, so I won't include the specifics of the 555 circuit.

For completeness, here is my circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWmGns.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As I indicated above, `CLK1` is not an actual 50/50 square wave. It's generated by a 555. Both DC power supplies are mains transformers feeding full bridge rectifiers, smoothing capacitors, and a 78xx regulator.

The issue I am seeing is that when `Q1` turns on current flows in the primary. When `Q1` turns off, current stops in the primary. Some time later, a voltage spike occurs on the base of `Q1`, then turning it on briefly again. This spike is a mystery to me. I call this the "free" trigger.

I noticed this if I add a 472K (4.7 nF) capacitor the primary, I saw the "free" trigger of `Q1` move to the right in time. So I installed a 473K capacitor (47 nF) and the "free" trigger disappeared entirely. I'm not really sure what the output of this transformer should look like, but it at least looked normal once I did that.

why does this "free" triggering occur? Why does the capacitor fix the problem? Does the capacitor cause other problems when trying to operate a gate drive transformer?

Picture of the physical setup

[image]

[image]

[image]

CH1: secondary of `XFMR1`, CH2: base of `Q1`

[image]

[image]

CH1: secondary of `XFMR1`, CH2: AC coupling to `V1`

[image]

CH1: secondary of `XFMR1`, CH2: Base of `Q1`

[image]

Ch2: secondary of `XMFR1`, CH2: Base of `Q1`. 472K  cap. in parallel with primary of transformer

[image]

CH1: secondary of `XMFR1`, CH2: Base of `Q1`. 473K cap. in parallel with primary of transformer.

Comment: have you tried to put a diode in reverse at primary side?

Comment: What is the intended function of the circuit?

Comment: What is the collector-base breakdown voltage of the transistor? You need to monitor the *collector* of Q1 (warning : probable high voltage!) The inductive spike may be breaking down the C-B junction giving you the free trigger. The capacitor will slow the rise time, delaying the breakdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Q1 turns off, current stops in the primary

No it certainly doesn't. Whatever current was flowing will continue to flow by generating as much voltage as needed to breakdown Q1 and force conduction of that current through Q1.

For a flyback design you need a secondary load and you need a snubber across the primary to protect the transistor. You need a secondary load because you are storing energy in the primary when Q1 conducts and, that energy needs to dissipate somewhere i.e. the secondary load. The snubber catches what energy can't be transferred to protect Q1.

The capacitor is partially acting as a snubber in that it recirculates the energy and dissipates some of it through the repeated circulation in the primary but unless you dissipate what you have stored you will drive the transformer into saturation and this may lead to final destruction of Q1. You should try a 100 ohm resistor in series with the snubber capacitor as a ball-park value.

Comment: I agree, my terminology is wrong. What I meant is when I measured the current from the 12 VDC power supply into the primary, it changes when Q1 turns off. I will conduct additional tests with your recommended changes to the circuit.

Comment: I did more tests and this pretty much explains it. The collector voltage was really high. I was thinking this might just destroy my transistor, but apparently all that actually happens is it just gets turned on again by the voltage spike.

Comment: Yes this can happen sometimes and is more often seen in mosfets doing similar jobs. The question to you is, are you willing to risk it or use a snubber?

Comment: Mostly, this circuit was about learning. Can I just use a resistor on the primary side?

Comment: The resistor could work but of course it represents a permanent load inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Your precise symptoms are the very reason we have flyback diodes.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

Answer (score 1):

> When Q1 turns off, current stops in the primary.

I'm not quite able to follow your description. If you mean that you turn off Q1 by removing V2 then I suspect that you could be having this trouble:

[image]

*Figure 1. Unexpected sneak path.*

With V2 off there is no positive bias on Q2's collector. It behaves as a pair of back to back diodes and any current from CLK1 can flow through its b-e junction (as normal) or its b-c junction (which it normally wouldn't). This b-c current may be enough to turn on Q1 despite having two diode drops in series. There's a lowish 1k drive to Q2's base so the Q2 base voltage will rise to about 0.7 V giving 0.35 V to each of the sneak-path junctions.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgRzBy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. An improved circuit?*

The circuit is a poor form of AND gate. Try moving Q2's collector in place of the GND connection on Q1 as in common examples of discrete AND gates. This will invert the logic of CLK1 but I don't think that will bother you.

Comment: I am somewhat confused by your comment "with V2 off". I do not turn off V2 in this circuit.

Comment: OK. I misunderstood your circuit. What is Q1 doing then?

Comment: It controls current from V1 through the transformer.